# VHDL TESTBENCH ERROR

Tags: vhdl

I have to write a testbench code for a block having two inputs which were "X" and "Y" with output "A". The behaviour of the block is addition of two input signals, added value to be stored in "A". Two inputs are 8 bit values and output has 9 bit width.

Here is my code for testbench but I am getting an error.. kindly help me out.

CODE:

```
library IEEE;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY intensity1_tb IS
END intensity1_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF intensity1_tb IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT intensity1
    PORT(
         X : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         Y : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         A : OUT  std_logic_vector(8 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal X : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := '00000000';
   signal Y : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := '00000000';           

    --Outputs
   signal A : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0) := '000000000';


BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: intensity1 PORT MAP (
          X => X,
          Y => Y,
          A => A
        );

   -- Clock process definitions

   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      wait for 100 ns;

 X <= "00000000";   
 Y <= "11111111";
 A <= "011111111";

         wait for 100 ns;

 X <= "00001111";   
 Y <= "11110000";
 A <= "011111111";

         wait for 100 ns;

 X <= "00001100";   
 Y <= "10011000";
 A <= "010100100";


         wait for 100 ns;


 X <= "01111000";   
 Y <= "10001110";
 A <= "100000110";

      end process;          

END;
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: A is an output of the DUT, so do not drive A.  If you intend to have an expected value, then name it something different, like Expected_A.  Then you can test it with an assert or an OSVVM Alert.  For more on OSVVM Alerts, see http://www.synthworks.com/blog/osvvm

Answer (score 1):

These single quotes:

```
   --Inputs
   signal X : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := '00000000';
   signal Y : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := '00000000';           

    --Outputs
   signal A : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0) := '000000000';
```

Should be double quotes.  After which your code analyzes. Without the entity/architecture for `uut` it's not possible to find further errors.